# How to disable transactions being published to sentry?

Tags: java, spring-boot, sentry

Even though I set the traces sample rate to 0.0 so as to stop the transactions being published to sentry in the spring boot application.We would be using sentry for error reporting but not for performance monitoring.

Thanks in advance!

```
sentry:
  dsn: -
  traces-sample-rate: 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to completely disable tracing with either:

```yaml
sentry:
  enable-tracing: false
```

or

```yaml
sentry:
  tracing-sample-rate: null
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/spring-boot/configuration/options/#enable-tracing):

> enableTracing
>
> A boolean value, if true, transactions and trace data will be generated and captured. This will set the traces-sample-rate to the recommended default of 1.0 if traces-sample-rate is not defined. Note that traces-sample-rate and traces-sampler take precedence over this option.
>
> tracesSampleRate
>
> A number between 0 and 1, controlling the percentage chance a given transaction will be sent to Sentry. (0 represents 0% while 1 represents 100%.) Applies equally to all transactions created in the app. Either this or tracesSampler must be defined to enable tracingThe process of logging the events that took place during a request, often across multiple services.

The JavaDoc for `tracesSampleRate` in `SentryOptions.java` also mentions that `null` disables it:

```java
/**
   * Sets the tracesSampleRate Can be anything between 0.0 and 1.0 or null (default), to disable it.
   *
   * @param tracesSampleRate the sample rate
   */
  public void setTracesSampleRate(final @Nullable Double tracesSampleRate) {
    if (!SampleRateUtils.isValidTracesSampleRate(tracesSampleRate)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "The value "
              + tracesSampleRate
              + " is not valid. Use null to disable or values between 0.0 and 1.0.");
    }
    this.tracesSampleRate = tracesSampleRate;
  }
```